# SQL Server with XML and selecting child nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have the following XML:

```
<tests>
   <test>1</test>
   <test>2</test>
   <test>3</test>
</tests>
```

And I am trying the following query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
    @Tests xml=null
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT
      doc.col.value('(test)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)')
   FROM 
      @Tests.nodes('//tests') AS doc(col)
END
```

But it only returns me a value from the first

What am I missing here?

Comment: This was the only question here tagged 'mssql'.  Let's take a litte more care with tag choices in the future, okay?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I will try to keep the tage more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the `<test>` nodes, you need to use a different XPath in your `.nodes()`

```
SELECT
    doc.col.value('(.)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)')
FROM 
      @Tests.nodes('/tests/test') AS doc(col)
```

That way, you get an enumeration of all `<test>` nodes and you can select the inner XML from those using the `(.)` XPath.

Answer (score 2):

The XPath in the `nodes()` function is only returning 1 record.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT
  doc.col.value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(50)')
FROM @Tests.nodes('//test') AS doc(col)
```